# How to use the first line of my data for rescaling the data in gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot, data-visualization

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
1 3 4 5 5 3 4
4 5 5 3 5 3 2
3 4 5 3 5 2 5
```

I use this file to build a heatmap in gnuplot with this code:

```
set term png
set out "test.png"
set pm3d map
set size ratio 1
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set tics out nomirror
stats 'test.dat' nooutput
N = STATS_records
M = STATS_columns
splot 'test.dat' matrix using ($1/(N-1)*10-5):($2/(M-1)*3-(-1)):3 notitle
set out
```

It works and everything is good.

Except that now I would like to remove the constants in the code (10, 5, 3, -1) and replace them with a header in my data file.

The data file should become:

```
10, 5, 3, -1
1 3 4 5 5 3 4
4 5 5 3 5 3 2
3 4 5 3 5 2 5
```

and the code something similar to:

```
delta_x = ???
x_min = ???
delta_y = ???
y_min = ???
set term png
set out "test.png"
set pm3d map
set size ratio 1
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set tics out nomirror
stats 'test.dat' nooutput
N = STATS_records
M = STATS_columns
splot 'test.dat' matrix using ($1/(N-1)*delta_x-min_x):($2/(M-1)*delta_y-min_y):3 notitle
set out
```

I should also stop using the first row when loading data for the heatmap, so $1, $2 are somehow wrong.

How can I use the first line only to read the variable and start to read the data from the second line of my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stats` with `every` to get constants from the first line, then skip first line using `awk` output.

```
stats 'test.dat' every ::0::0 using 1:2 nooutput
delta_x = STATS_min_x
x_min = STATS_min_y
stats 'test.dat' every ::0::0 using 3:4 nooutput
delta_y = STATS_min_x
y_min = STATS_min_y
set size ratio 1
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set tics out nomirror
stats 'test.dat' every ::1 nooutput
N = STATS_records
M = STATS_columns
splot '<awk "NR>1 {print}" test.dat' matrix using ($1/(N-1)*delta_x-x_min):($2/(M-1)*delta_y-y_min):3 notitle
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! There are only two problems: 1- I get this warning twice: "Warning:  Can't compute errors of slope and intercept. Not enough data points." Is there a way to solve? 2- Sometimes the x axis or the y axis start before or end after my boundaries and I get some portion of my plot all white. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: alternatively, instead of `splot '<awk "NR>1 {print}" test.dat'`, you might use `splot 'test.dat' skip 1`